# Partial derivative of composition function

Tags: partial-derivative

Given $F(x,y,z) = f(g(x+y),h(y+z))$ what is the partial derivatives of $F$ using partial derivative of $f,g,h$ for $x,y,z$?

I don't have any clue, i used to solve when i know the function and not in the abstract form.

**Edit** : Let $f(u,v)$ and so :

$\frac{\partial F(x,y,z)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial f(g(x+y),h(y+z))}{\partial u}  \frac{d g(x+y)}{d x} = \frac{\partial f(g(x+y),h(y+z))}{\partial u}  g'(x+y)$

$\frac{\partial F(x,y,z)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial f(g(x+y),h(y+z))}{\partial u}  \frac{d g(x+y)}{d y} + \frac{\partial f(g(x+y),h(y+z))}{\partial u}  \frac{d h(y+z)}{d y } = \frac{\partial f(g(x+y),h(y+z))}{\partial u}  g'(x+y)+ \frac{\partial f(g(x+y),h(y+z))}{\partial u} h'(y+z) $

$\frac{\partial F(x,y,z)}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial f(g(x+y),h(y+z))}{\partial u}  \frac{d h(y+z)}{d z} = \frac{\partial f(g(x+y),h(y+z))}{\partial u} h'(y+z) $

Is this answer correct ?

Comment: The partial derivative with respect to what variable? Also, have you tried using the chain rule?

Comment: @memerson $x,y,z$